# Solution elements dissapeared from Ribbon Workbench

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-365, crm-ribbon-workbench

Some Ribbon buttons sudenly dissapeared from environment (from some Entities), and in Ribbon Workbench solution elements are not displayed and everything is greyed out (please see the image).
I am Systemadmin in this environment. What could be the issue here?

[image: Ribbon Workbench]

I checked my security roles, I am still admin there. Cleared the cache, reloaded, problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the loaded solution does only contain the required entity and use the latest version of Ribbon Workbench:

https://www.xrmtoolbox.com/plugins/RibbonWorkbench2016/